# Can't get Julia Flux to work for simple linear regression test

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I'm a Julia user new to Flux and machine learning.  As a first test and to understand how Flux works, I tried using Flux to estimate a simple linear regression model.  But clearly I'm doing something wrong, as training the model using train! does not give me the expected OLS coefficients.  This surprised me; since linear regression is a simple convex optimization problem, I would have expected gradient descent to quickly converge to the optimum.  So I assume I've misunderstood something about how train! works.

Here's my code:

```
using Flux
using Flux: @epochs
using GLM

# Load data: The features of the Iris data set
features = Flux.Data.Iris.features();
x = features[1:3,:];
y = features[4,:];

J, N = size(x); # number of explanatory variables, number of observations

model = Chain(Dense(J,1)); # define the model

loss(x,y) = Flux.Losses.mse(model(x),y); # define the loss function

function loss_all(X,y) # and define a full-sample loss function
    l = 0;
    for i in 1:length(y)
        l += loss(X[:,i],y[i]);
    end
    return l
end

loss_all(x,y)
@epochs 10000 Flux.train!(loss, params(model), [(x,y)], Descent(0.01)); # train the model
loss_all(x,y)

# How does the result compare to OLS (should be exactly the same)?
x_augmented = vcat(ones(1,N),x);
ols = inv(x_augmented*transpose(x_augmented))*x_augmented*y
y_hat = transpose(x_augmented)*ols;
sse = sum((y_hat - y).^2)
```

I expect I'm making a silly mistake, but I would really appreciate if someone could help me identify the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is to make sure `y` has a shape matching `model(x)`:

```
y = features[4:4,:];
```

Note that:

```
Flux.Losses.mse(model(x),y)
```

expands to:

```
mean((model(x) .- y).^2)
```

so `model(x)` and `y` should have the same shape (after my fix they are `(1,150)`). In your original code it was `(1,150)` vs `(150,)` which meant that the dimensions got broadcasted to `(150,150)` after `(model(x) .- y).^2`.

Comment: Thanks so much, Bogumil!  I think you meant

 y = features[[4],:];

But this solves the problem.  Thanks so much!